# IdentityServer4 with AspNetIdentity. How to get WebApi access to UserDb

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

there is a configured authorization service on `IdentityServer4`.
The database for it with webApi access must be moved to a separate project.

access to webApi with users is possible only for authorized users through IdentityServer4.

1. L for `IdentityServer4`, this is just another api (scope) to which you need to provide access.
2. to work with users, you need to use `AspNetIdentity` to access the `UserManager <ApplicationUser>`and`RoleManager <ApplicationUser>` services

   If I add `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>()`, then authorization through IdentityServer4 stops working.
    If I do not add, then `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` and `RoleManager<ApplicationUser>` services are not available.

Setting up webApi for users

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()      // authorization with token (IdentityServer4) stops working
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddMvcCore()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AdminsOnly", policyUser =>
                {
                    policyUser.RequireClaim("role", "admin");
                });
                options.AddPolicy("ManagerOnly", policyUser =>
                {
                    policyUser.RequireClaim("role", "manager");
                });
            })
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000"; 
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;         
                options.ApiName = "UserDbApi";                
                options.EnableCaching = true;
                options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            });

        services.AddCors(options =>        
        {
            options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
            {
                policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5003")       //access Js client
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors("default");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Access to the test controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
      // Access works only with a token issued by IdentityServer4
    }
}
```

Js client

```
var config = {
    authority: "http://localhost:5000",
    client_id: "js",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5003/callback.html",
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope: "openid profile custom.profile api1 UserDbApi",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5003/index.html",
    checkSessionInterval: 30000,
    revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:5003/callback-silent.html',
    accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 60
};
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);

function getInfo() {
    mgr.getUser().then(function (user) {
        var url = "https://localhost:7000/api/values";

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            log(xhr.status, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + user.access_token);
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

I am hampered by the authorization provided AspNetIdentity!!!

Please Help!

Comment: Have a go with `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Roles = "SuperAdmin")]` on the `Get` action.

Comment: It works thanks a lot

Comment: If I use a JS client, then such a system is not needed AspNetIdentity uses a cookie-based authorization system?